# Bucles en Cadenas de texto

Tags: javascript, string, bucles

Mediante un bucle necesito separar vocales y consonante de una cadena de texto.

Ejemplo:

````
```
    const texto = 'bucles en la cadena';
```
````

La salida debería ser así: u e e a a e a b c l s n l c d n, en el orden que están en la cadena, intenté hacerlo con un bucle, pero solo logro iterar, mas no separar las vocales de las consonantes.

edt: no usar regex

Answer (score 1):

```
let vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
let consonantes = ["b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"]

let texto = 'bucles en la cadena'.toLowerCase(); // esto para que no diferencia las mayusculas de las minusculas

function separar(texto){
  let result = ""; // cadena
  for (const letra of texto) // hacemos 2 for seguidos y vamos encadenando primero las vocales, luego las consonantes, si hay simbolos no los incluye
    if(vocales.includes(letra))
      result += `${letra} `;
  for (const letra of texto)
    if(consonantes.includes(letra))
      result += `${letra} `;
  return result; // devolvemos la cadena
}

texto = separar(texto);
console.log(texto);
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas utilizar bucles, puedes hacerlo con expresiones regulares, es mucho más sencillo:

```js
function ordenarTexto(texto) {
  let result = texto.replace(/ /g,''); // juntamos todo el texto => buclesenlacadena
  let result1 = result.match(/[aeiou]/g).toString(); // extraemos solo las vocales => u,e,e,a,a,e,a
  let result2 = result.replace(/[aeiou]/g,"").split('').join(','); // extraemos las letras que no son vocales => b,c,l,s,n,l,c,d,n
  return result1 + "," + result2; // juntamos los dos resultados
}

console.log(ordenarTexto("bucles en la cadena"));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Utilizando Bucles

Comparas cada caracter, si es una vocal lo añades a una lista de vocales, si es una consonante lo añades a una de consonantes.

Una vez terminas de iterar por todo el string original solo necesitas juntar los dos arreglos.

### ```js
function getVolwelConsonants(str) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  const orderedVowels = [];
  const orderedConsonants = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.includes(str[i])) {
      orderedVowels.push(str[i]);
      
      continue;
    }
    
    if (str[i] === ' ') {
      continue;
    }

    orderedConsonants.push(str[i]);
  }
  
  return [...orderedVowels, ...orderedConsonants];
}

const result = getVolwelConsonants('bucles en la cadena');
console.log(result);
console.log(result.join(' '));
```

### Utilizando regex

Para seleccionar las vocales:

```
/[aeiou]/g
```

Para seleccionar lo que no son vocales o espacios en blanco:

```
/[^aeiou\s]/g
```

Luego al resultado le aplicas el spread operator para juntar todo en un arreglo y tienes tu resultado

```js
function getVowelConsonants(str) {
  return [...str.match(/[aeiou]/g), ...str.match(/[^aeiou\s]/g)];
}

const result = getVowelConsonants('bucles en la cadena');
console.log(result);

// Si necesitas el resultado como un `string`
console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Comment: sin usar expresiones regulares solo bucles

Comment: @AngelVera editado, ¿qué tal ahora?

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar el operador ternario:
(Modificado):Sensible a mayúsculas

```
const cadena = 'Hola mundo'
let es_vocal= [];
let no_vocal = [];
const vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
var cadena_sin_espacio = cadena.replace(/\s+/g, '')
var cadena_split = cadena_sin_espacio.split('');
cadena_split.forEach(element => vocales.includes(element) ? es_vocal.push(element): no_vocal.push(element));
console.log(es_vocal.concat(no_vocal))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const s = 'bucles en la cadena'
const v = 'aeiou'
const c = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'

for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  for(let j=0; j < v.length; j++) {
    if(v[j] === s[i]) {
      console.log(s[i])
    }
  }
}
for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  for(let j=0; j < c.length; j++) {
    if(c[j] === s[i]) {
      console.log(s[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Una manera en que lo resolví, si alguien puede hacerlo mas simple sin usar regex, lo comparte por favor